# Uncountability of increasing functions on N

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I believe I have made a reasonable attempt to answer the following question. I would like a confirmation of my proof to be correct, or help as to why it is incorrect.

Question:
Let $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be increasing if $f(n+1) \ge f(n)$ for all $n$. Is the set $A$ of functions $f$ countable or uncountable?

For each $f$ in $A$, there is a function $g: \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\} \to \mathbb{N} \cup\{0\}$ defined by $g(0)=f(1)$ and $g(n)=f(n+1)-f(n)$ for $n>0$. Conversely, for each $g: \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\} \to \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ with $g(0)>0$, there is an increasing function $f$ defined recursively by $f(1)=g(0)$ and $f(n+1)=f(n)+g(n)$ for $n>0$. Consequently, there is a bijection between $A$ and the set $B$, of $g: \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\} \to \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$, $g(0)>0$. If $B$ is uncountable, then $A$ must be uncountable.

The set $C$ of $h: \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\} \to \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ with $h(0)=1 $is a subset of $B$. For each real $x \in [1,2)$, there is a unique decimal expansion with 1 before the decimal point, ending NOT in trailing 9's. By defining for $n>0$, $h(n)=$ (n'th digit of x after decimal point), we have an injection from $[1,2)$ to the set $C$ (different $x$ => different decimal expansions => x maps to different h). Since the set of reals on $[1,2]$ is uncountable,
the set C is uncountable,
=> the set B is uncountable,
=> the set A is uncountable.

Answer (score 20):

This proof works but seems needlessly verbose. It is easier to prove that *strictly* increasing functions form an uncountable set (which implies that the monotone increasing are uncountable as well). This is because there is an obvious 1-1 correspondence between strictly increasing functions and infinite subsets of N (each such function is uniquely determined by its range). It is a standard result that there are uncountably many subsets of N, of which only countably many are finite. Hence, there are uncountably many infinite subsets.

Answer (score 14):

It is rather easy to apply the diagonalization argument directly. Let $\langle f_n\rangle$ be a sequence of increasing functions from the naturals to itself. Define a function $f$ recursively by $f(1)=1$ and
$$f(n+1)=f(n)+f_n(n+1)-f_n(n)+1.$$
The resulting function $f$ is clearly different from every function in the sequence $\langle f_n\rangle$.

Comment: Oh I really like this. +1

Comment: The resulting function $f$ need not be increasing, so doesn't belong to the set being considered.

Comment: (More precisely, $f(n+1) - f(n) = (f_n(n+1) - f_n(n)) -  (f_{n-1}(n) - f_{n-1}(n-1))$; since there's no relation between the rates of growth of $f_n$ and $f_{n-1}$ you can't determine if this difference is positive or negative.

Comment: @hunter Thank you, you are right, what I wrote was different from what I actually intended. I have fixed it now. That is exactly where the recursive definition comes in.

Comment: Note that this is exactly the diagonalisation argument for general functions composed with the OP's transformation.

Answer (score 6):

Your proof looks OK to me.  It's a little longer than needed though.

Right after you define your set $A$, what if we just restrict ourselves to a subset of $A$ given by the subset of monotone functions $t: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $t(n+1)-t(n) \in \{0,1\}$ and $t(0)=k$.

Then in your spirit, we can identify each $t$ with the infinite binary sequence of its step-wise differences.  Moreover, clearly for any infinite binary sequence we can construct the unique $t$ that gets related to it.  Then by Cantor's diagonalization argument we know $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable and we're done.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to show that $A$ is uncountable : Show that if $B=\{f_n: n\in N\}\subset A$ then $B\ne A$ as follows:

Let $g(n)=\max \{1+f_j(n): j\leq n\}.$

We have $g(n)> f_n(n)$ for every $n. $ So $g\ne f_n$ for every  $n.$ So $g \not \in B.$

For each $ n $ we have $g(n)=1+f_{j_n}(n)$ for some $j_n\leq n . $ So $g(n+1)=\max \{1+f_j(n+1):j\leq n+1\}\geq 1+f_{j_n}(n+1)\geq 1+f_{j_n}(n)=g(n). $ So $ g\in A. $